# How to delete a line from a file that requires permission such as visudo using sed?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I want to add this command `timestamp=20` at the end of `visudo` file which will increase the sudo time for 20 min. This way I'll be able to use my bash script to install many applications. After I am done, I want to delete the same command from the `visudo` file.

My question might look trivial, but since `visudo` needs permission to edit so I don't know how to use to sed in a file that needs permission

Here is what I came with:

```
echo -e "add the timestamp" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers #This will add the timestamp command
sed '31,35' /etc/sudoers #This will remove the timestamp command
```

The first command works perfectly. However, running the second command shows this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 5: missing command

Any suggestions or modifications I can use ??

Comment: The error message you posted indicates that the "d" was not there when you ran the sed command, but the answer you posted below makes the file be edited in-place.

Comment: Further, you need to add "timestamp_timeout", not "timestamp".  And the sed should really delete one line matching "Defaults timestamp_timeout=20", not five lines from the file.  This whole scenario is suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem. I added the option `-i` and `d` letter after the number 35. 
The numbers 31 and 35 meanse that sed will delete everything between between line number 31 and line number 35.

I also added the command `sudo` so I can use `sed` in files that need permission...

Here is the final command:

> sudo sed '31,35d' -i /etc/sudoers